# Silverstripe 3.2: How to force a download of a file from the CMS with a button?

Tags: download, httprequest, httpresponse, silverstripe

I have a problem with downloading a pdf file by clicking a button from the CMS. I'm working with the module [BetterButtons](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons). The buttons itself works fine but there is an error on downloading the file. I always get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Warning at line 257 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/framework/control/HTTPResponse.php)

and

> [Recoverable Error] Object of class SS_HTTPResponse could not be
>   converted to string.

So I assume the line

> return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file($filedata, $fileName,
>   'application/pdf');

is wrong or something is wrong with $filedata... What is the right way to do that?

My code:

In my Dataobject where I have the download button:

```
private static $better_buttons_actions = array (
            'printFilesPDF'
);

public function getBetterButtonsActions() {
        $fields = parent::getBetterButtonsActions();
        $fields->push(BetterButtonCustomAction::create('printFilesPDF', 'Print files'));
        return $fields;
}

public function printFilesPDF() {

        $filedata = File::find("assets/PDF/myFile.pdf");
        $fileName = "myFile.pdf";
        return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file($filedata, $fileName, 'application/pdf');

}
```

Comment: whenever you get a "500 error" returned you need to change to dev mode, that will give you an error and would maybe help you resolve or someoneelse here help you resolve

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering so fast. I am in dev mode.. found out the "real" error after reloading the page after clicking the button: [Recoverable Error] Object of class SS_HTTPResponse could not be converted to string. Unfortunately still don't know what to do :( ... can you help me?

Comment: @iraira I ran into the same problem. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @csy_dot_io Yes, I find a solution. I will post it as an answer later when I am at home.

Comment: That would be perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I post the answer below. Hope this solution fits for your needs.. its not the best one but it works for me. If you find another/better one it would be nice if you share it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is not the best one but it works for me.

I let the file open in a new tab so the user can download it by themselves or just look at it in the browser window:

First instead of using a `BetterButtonCustomAction` I use `BetterButtonLink`:

```
public function getBetterButtonsActions() {
    $fields = parent::getBetterButtonsActions();
    $fields->push(new BetterButtonLink('Download the file', "assets/myfile.pdf"));
}
```

By using `BetterButtonLink` I was facing the following problem:
Every time I click on the button it tries to open the PDF in the CMS admin via an AJAX request which results in encoded text being displayed. A simple solution you can find here: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons/issues/64

So my final code is

```
public function getBetterButtonsActions() {
    $fields = parent::getBetterButtonsActions();
    $fields->push(new BetterButtonLink_NewWindow('Download the file', "assets/myfile.pdf"));
}
```

And the `BetterButtonLink_NewWindow` code:

```
class BetterButtonLink_NewWindow extends BetterButtonLink {

    /**
     * Gets the HTML representing the button
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonHTML() {
        return sprintf(
            '<a class="ss-ui-button %s" href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>',
            $this->extraClass(),
            $this->getButtonLink(),
            $this->getButtonText()
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a "File" object you intend to pass a string to the send_file function.

I'd change the the line

```
 $filedata = File::find("assets/PDF/myFile.pdf");
```

to

```
$filedata = file_get_contents(File::find("assets/PDF/myFile.pdf")->getFullPath());
```

However, that would be better written to check that File::find(...) returns a file and not null!

Comment: I tried your solution but still get the same error: "Object of class SS_HTTPResponse could not be converted to string"

Comment: Could you test with a simple return like `return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file("test", "test.html", 'text/html');` first. Just to be sure where the error is.  Barrys tip should work but you are still getting that error that seems odd.. What is the SS version you are using?

Comment: so my comment was to correct the data being sent into the HTTP request.  I'm also not sure about how you are using the request as you seem to be adding it into an action... normally I make that the last return of a action function on a controller... can you try making that?  A simple controller that outputs this as one of its actions without the better buttons stuff.

Comment: Hmm...after a few tests I found out that the code/the function works perfectly when you trigger it from the frontend (e.g. when I click a button in the template), but don't work when I trigger this function from the CMS (via betterbuttons action)... do you know what the reason could be?

Answer (score 1):

File::find() returns a File object if a file exists or null if it isn't. It never returns binary data, which is why HTTPResponse won't convert it to a string.

If file_get_contents is not working, check that it isn't disabled on your machine.

```
//attempt to find the file
$file = File::find("path/to/my/file.txt");

//you need to check that the file is File and not null
if($file && $file instanceof File) {
    //get the file path
    $path = $file->getFullPath();

    //get the file data. If file_get_contents() doesn't work, you might need fopen() or file() instead
    $fileData = file_get_contents($path);
    $fileName = "myFile.pdf";
    return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file($fileData, $fileName, 'application/pdf');
}
```

Comment: Ok..I made some tests and found out that your code works perfectly in the frontend (e.g. when I click a button in the template), but I still get the same error when I trigger this function from the CMS... do you know what the reason could be?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a [`LiteralField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-LiteralField.html) to create a link to a file. By setting the class of the link to `ss-ui-button` we can make the link look like a button.

Here is an example link to a specific file:

```
LiteralField::create(
    'DownloadLink',
    '<a href="assets/myfile.pdf" target="_blank" class="ss-ui-button" download>Download the file</a>'
);
```

This could be used in the `getCMSFields` or `getCMSActions` to make the button display in the fields area or in the buttons area.

Here is an example link to a `$has_one` controlled file through `getCMSFields`:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    if ($this->File()->exists()) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', 
            LiteralField::create(
                'DownloadLink',
                '<a href="' . $this->File()->Link() . '" target="_blank" class="ss-ui-button" download>Download the file</a>'
            )
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}
```